# Layout view does not wrap content after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view to show some data. When the app is launched it looks correct as follows with wrap content for height. After I scroll past the last item, I am able to keep scrolling and the data is no longer wrapped, looking like match parent instead for height. Scrolling back up, everything has changed to match parent for the height.

Using past references here, I have tried with ConstraintLayouts and switched height wrapping between the parent layout and the recyclerview itself. Both doesn't help. I am guessing this has to do more with the xml. Please advice.

This is what I expect to always get. This is what I current get when app launches, but changes after I scroll to last item.

[image]

When I scroll to last item this happens.

[image]

Now if I scroll back up, the height is no longer wrapped. Everything seems to have changed to match parent.

[image]

This is xml for the custom view I am using to inflate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/feed_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:text="Test Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_title"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/feed_title"
        tools:text="This is some random description for testing purposes. Other wise just typing on to create more stuff..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is layout for the Recycler View which is placed on a Fragment activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.CurrentFeedFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/current_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is over at my FragmentActivity where I am loading the data for the RecyclerView.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_feed, container, false);
        initiateTestData();
        loadDataToRecyclerView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initiateTestData(){

        testTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        testDescriptions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 5; i < 25; i++) {
            testTitles.add("title " + i);
            testDescriptions.add("This is some random description for testing purposes. Other wise just typing on to create more stuff... " + i);
            Log.d(TAG, "initiateTestData: " + "title " + i);
        }
    }

    private void loadDataToRecyclerView(View v){
        Log.d(TAG, "loadDataToRecyclerView: " + testTitles.size());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.current_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(testTitles, testDescriptions, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
```

Don't think this is relevant. But for reference, this is my adapter class.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "FeedAdapter";

    private List<String> titles;
    private List<String> descriptions;
    private Context context;

    public FeedAdapter(List<String> titles, List<String> descriptions, Context context) {
        this.titles = titles;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_current_feed, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        holder.feedTitle.setText(titles.get(i));
        holder.feedDescription.setText(descriptions.get(i));

        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked: " + titles.get(i));
            Toast.makeText(context, titles.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView feedTitle;
        TextView feedDescription;
        RelativeLayout layout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            feedTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_title);
            feedDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_description);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recycler view height is wrap_content

And recycler view item height match_parent

I would think you'd want them the other way around.

The RV's height = match_parent, i.e. the recycler view occupies all available height.

The RV item's height = wrap_content, i.e. each item only as tall as it needs to be, so that multiple items can fit.